# Get ubuntu bootable on different machine

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, bootable-media

I have ubuntu studio installed on a hard drive that I just moved to a different computer. I can boot the other distributions I have on the drive, but not ubuntu studio. Whenever I try, it shows the studio logo, and does nothing. Is there a way to make it bootable easily, or should I just reinstall it?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you have just GNU/Linux distros or windows as well but I would try reinstalling grub from a live cd (google how to do this if you dont know).

Comment: Grub seems to be working fine though. I use it to boot suse, arch, slackware, and fedora, and the ubuntu studio logo appears like it should when booting, it just never moves beyond that, so I assume it is unable to be booted.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep backup your Home folder, you will be able to reinstall Ubuntu Studio and have all your settings restored. The only thing is that you will need to reinstall each app that you had installed previously.

However if you make a backup list of installed packages, life is easier. Try this:

```
dpkg --get-selections > installed-software
```

and then:

```
dpkg --set-selections < installed-software
```

Comment: Haha, ok, thanks, I was afraid of this, but I guess I will just do it. My home folder is huge, and I have way too many programs installed.

Comment: Well if you use those dpkg commands, it will restore them all. A good habit to get into with any Linux Distro is just have one partition for your home folder. Backing up /etc might be beneficial as well.

Comment: The problem turned out to be the graphics driver. I booted into safe graphics mode and installed the new ones. Everything is working fine now.